# About the intrepreter for AIML

Tags: aiml

I tried to build a chatbot in AIML. I downloaded the codes from http://nlp-addiction.com/chatbot/mathbot/ but couldn't get the idea about how to run the program. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

An AIML file isn't program code, it's a data file (much like any other xml file).

You need to use an interpreter like [Program-AB](https://code.google.com/p/program-ab/) to load and use the file to answer queries.

If you just want to test the contents and formatting of the aiml file, you could use [Pandorabots](http://www.pandorabots.com) and load the file into a blank bot fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AIML file isn't program code. It's just like a data format. You can learn about it more from here : http://www.alicebot.org/aiml.html

Answer (score 0):

AIML is a data encoding format that tells the bot when to do what to do. Many interpreters can be used to interpret the aiml tags.

One of them is [PyAIML](http://pyaiml.sourceforge.net/) which is python based interpreter fairly simple to use.